# Agda: Reading a line of standard input as a String instead of a Costring

Tags: io, agda

I am trying to write a simple program that reads a line from standard input, reverses it, and then prints the reversed string.

Unfortunately the native `getLine` function reads a `Costring`; I can only reverse `String`s; and there is no function that takes a `Costring` to a `String`.

How can I amend this program to compile?

```
module EchoInputReverse where

-- Agda standard library 0.7
open import Data.List using (reverse)
open import Data.String
open import Foreign.Haskell using (Unit)
open import IO.Primitive

postulate
  getLine : IO Costring

{-# COMPILED getLine getLine #-}

main : IO Unit
main = 
  getLine >>= (λ s → 
  -- NOTE: Need a (toString : Costring → String) here. Or some other strategy.
  return (toCostring (fromList (reverse (toList (toString s))))) >>= (λ s' → 
  putStrLn s'))
```

Answer (score 12):

You can't do that, at least not directly. The problem is that `Costring` can be infinite in size, while `String`s must be finite.

Imagine running the program as `prog < /dev/zero`, what should happen? The `reverse` function can produce the first element only after reaching the end of the input list and that may never happen.

We need to express the fact that converting a `Costring` to `String` can fail. One way to do it is to use the partiality monad. Let's take a look at the definition:

```
data _⊥ {a} (A : Set a) : Set a where
  now   : (x : A) → A ⊥
  later : (x : ∞ (A ⊥)) → A ⊥
```

So, we can either have a value of type `A` right `now`, or we need to wait for `later`. But notice the `∞` symbol: that means we can actually wait forever (as in there can be infinite number of `later` constructors).

I'll merge the conversion and reversing into one function. Imports first:

```
open import Category.Monad.Partiality
open import Coinduction
open import Data.Char
open import Data.Colist
  using ([]; _∷_)
open import Data.List
  using ([]; _∷_; List)
open import Data.String
open import Data.Unit
open import IO
```

Now, the type of our `reverse` function should mention that we take a `Costring` as an input but also that returning a `String` may fail. The implementation is then fairly simple, it's the usual reverse with accumulator:

```
reverse : Costring → String ⊥
reverse = go []
  where
  go : List Char → Costring → String ⊥
  go acc []       = now (fromList acc)
  go acc (x ∷ xs) = later (♯ go (x ∷ acc) (♭ xs))
```

However, we can print a `String`, but not `String ⊥`! That's where `IO` helps: we can interpret the `later` constructors as "do nothing" and if we find `now` constructor, we can `putStrLn` the `String` it contains.

```
putStrLn⊥ : String ⊥ → IO ⊤
putStrLn⊥ (now   s) = putStrLn s
putStrLn⊥ (later s) = ♯ return tt >> ♯ putStrLn⊥ (♭ s)
```

Notice that I use the `IO` from `IO` module, not the one from `IO.Primitive`. This is basically a layer built on the postulates, so it's a bit nicer. But if you want to use `getLine` with this, you have to write:

```
import IO.Primitive as Prim

postulate
  primGetLine : Prim.IO Costring

{-# COMPILED primGetLine getLine #-}

getLine : IO Costring
getLine = lift primGetLine
```

And finally, we can write the `main` function:

```
main = run (♯ getLine >>= λ c → ♯ putStrLn⊥ (reverse c))
```

---

Compiling this program using `C-c C-x C-c` and then running it, we get the expected:

```
$ cat test
hello world
$ prog < test    
dlrow olleh
```

Comment: This approach involves quite a lot of type gymnastics. Does it buy you much over just asserting (technically incorrectly) that `getLine : IO String`?

Comment: Well, it gives you precise types, which is fairly important in languages such as Agda. But other than that, no. By the way, there's also `readFiniteFile`, which is also "postulated" with a wrong type, but unlike `getLine`, it can actually tell you when it doesn't work (it raises exception when given non-physical files).

Comment: > `putStrLn⊥ (later s) = ♯ return tt >> ♯ putStrLn⊥ (♭ s)`

(1) Why the `♯ return tt`? This appears to return a `⊤` and immediately discards it.
(2) In `♯ putStrLn⊥ (♭ s)` does the `♭` "force" the execution of `s`?
(3) Since this is recursing on the right side, I don't see how this computation will terminate.

Comment: The `♯ return tt` is there so that the corecursion is still productive. When you define a value in this way (that is, using corecursion), the termination checker will make sure you are introducing at least one constructor before recursing. The `♭` doesn't force execution in this sense, it's more like evaluation of the outermost constructor (but yes, `♯` is called delay and `♭` is called force). Other way to think about it is that `♯` creates "lazy" values and `♭` evaluates them.

Comment: As for the right recursion - it will terminate if the `Costring` given to `reverse` was finite. Because if it was, then there will be a finite number of `later` constructors, which means that the IO will go through finite number of `return tt` and then finally print the string.

Comment: Also, as for precise types, let me make a comparison. If you define `n : ℕ`, you not only state that `n` is of type `ℕ`, but also that its evaluation will finish in finite amout of time; if you define it as `n : ℕ ⊥`, you still state that there's something of type `ℕ`, but you now acknowledge that its computation might not finish. Postulating `getLine : IO String` feels like using `{-# NO_TERMINATION_CHECK #-}` and pretending it really terminates.

Answer (score 7):

Saizan on #agda points out that one could just postulate that `getLine : IO String` instead of `getLine : IO Costring`. This works. So you get:

```
module EchoInputReverse where

-- Agda standard library 0.7
open import Data.List using (reverse)
open import Data.String
open import Foreign.Haskell using (Unit)
open import IO.Primitive

postulate
  getLine : IO String

{-# COMPILED getLine getLine #-}

main : IO Unit
main = 
  getLine >>= (λ s → 
  return (toCostring (fromList (reverse (toList s)))) >>= (λ s' → 
  putStrLn s'))
```

---

The downside is that this approach asserts that `getLine` always returns a *finite* string, which may not be correct in the case of `prog < /dev/zero` as @Vitus points out.

But I don't think this matters. If `getLine` does in fact returns an infinite string then neither this solution nor @Vitus's solution will yield a program that terminates. They have equivalent behavior.

It would be ideal to detect whether the input was infinite and yield an error in that case. But this kind of infinity detection on IO is not possible in general.