# Agda: how to do non-terminating IO (getLine) without (the deprecated?) ∞-style coinduction?

Tags: io, agda, coinduction, non-termination

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808186/agda-reading-a-line-of-standard-input-as-a-string-instead-of-a-costring) about how to do `getLine` in Agda the main answer suggests using the partiality monad to deal with the possible non-termination of working with the resulting Costring.

On the other hand, in version 2.5.3 the manual page on [Coinduction](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.3/language/coinduction.html) advises against ∞, saying it can be used to prove absurdity. However ∞ is used in the definition of both [IO.IO and IO.run](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/IO.html#839) and the [partiality monad](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Category.Monad.Partiality.html#920).

Questions:

1. Is it possible to do partiality and non-terminating IO using the standard library without ∞? If not, what are the alternatives?
2. Is the standard library/documentation outdated?
3. Is the problem with ∞ due to the [interaction with sized types](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/1946)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at my work in progress [agda-sizedIO](https://github.com/gallais/agda-sizedIO) for a more modern copattern-based approach to IO in Agda. The main types are [here](https://gallais.github.io/agda-sizedIO/Sized.IO.html#IO′) and there's a [run function](https://gallais.github.io/agda-sizedIO/Sized.IO.html#run) which produces a `Prim.IO` just like in the old style. You can see how to use the [sized Colist](https://gallais.github.io/agda-sizedIO/Sized.Colist.html) in e.g. the [cat example](https://gallais.github.io/agda-sizedIO/cat.html).

Comment: I haven't defined `Sized.Partiality` but it shouldn't be too hard: it's basically a `Sized.Colist` which doesn't store values on the conses but does have one at the nil.

Comment: @gallais Your library looks very interesting! If you'd like to transform your comments into an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!